# Nodejs: How would I find a specific key value pair in a JSON object

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

Is there a way in Nodejs to find a specific key : value pair anywhere in an Object and if present return true.

Ie. Is `"DeviceType" : "Invalid Device Type"` found anywhere in the below object?

```
{
    "Config": {
        "Device": [{
            "DeviceType": 1,
            "Firmware": 216
        }],
        "Mobile": [{
            "DeviceType": "Invalid Device Type"
        }, {
            "DeviceType": "Invalid Device Type"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var j = {
    "Config": {
        "Device": [{
            "DeviceType": 1,
            "Firmware": 216
        }],
        "Mobile": [{
            "DeviceType": "Invalid Device Type"
        }, {
            "DeviceType": "Invalid Device Type"
        }]
    }    
};
var v = JSON.stringify(j);
var n = v.search('"DeviceType":"Invalid Device Type"'); // no white spaces between key value
if (n >= 0)
    console.log('found it!');
```

Comment: Thanks this seemed the most straight forward.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a ton of methods that include iterating through the objects, but unless you are doing something more complex than your example, I would suggest you convert the object to a string and use the`.indexOf` method to determine if the string is contained in the object string:

```
var obj = {
    "Config": {
        "Device": [{
            "DeviceType": 1,
            "Firmware": 216
        }],
        "Mobile": [{
            "DeviceType": "Invalid Device Type"
        }, {
            "DeviceType": "Invalid Device Type"
        }]
    }
};

var objString = JSON.stringify(obj);
var childString = "\"DeviceType\":\"Invalid Device Type\"";
var isStringPresent = objString.indexOf(childString) >= 0;
console.log(isStringPresent); // true

childString = "\"DeviceType\":\"asdfasfd\"";
isStringPresent = objString.indexOf(childString) >= 0;
console.log(isStringPresent); // false
```

You can also encapsulate the logic into a method:

```
function isStringContainedInObject(obj, str) {
    var objString = JSON.stringify(obj);
    return objString.indexOf(str) >= 0;
}

// invoke it
var obj = {
    "Config": {
        "Device": [{
            "DeviceType": 1,
            "Firmware": 216
        }],
        "Mobile": [{
            "DeviceType": "Invalid Device Type"
        }, {
            "DeviceType": "Invalid Device Type"
        }]
    }
};
var str = "\"DeviceType\":\"Invalid Device Type\"";
isStringContainedInObject(obj, str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's powerful once you wrap your head around it. And for your example it makes the solution simple.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (term, input) => objectScan(['**.DeviceType'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === term
})(input);

const input = { Config: { Device: [{ DeviceType: 1, Firmware: 216 }], Mobile: [{ DeviceType: 'Invalid Device Type' }, { DeviceType: 'Invalid Device Type' }] } };

console.log(find('Invalid Device Type', input));
// => true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)